# Is CSS display property animatable using keyframes?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I know I can't transition between `display` `none` and `block`, but I thought that I could do some kind of step animation by doing this:

```css
li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear;
  animation: winkle 1s linear;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 1s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 1s;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 2s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 2s;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 3s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 3s;
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 4s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 4s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes winkle {
  0%, 100% {
    display: none;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    display: block
  }
}
@keyframes winkle {
  0%, 100% {
    display: none;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    display: block
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

But actually this is not working. Can you confirm this is not possible? Is there any other solution? I thought of this but it doesn't work either. If you can come up with something better, it would be greatly appreciated.

```css
li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear;
  animation: winkle 1s linear;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 1s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 1s;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 2s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 2s;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 3s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 3s;
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 4s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 4s;
}
li {
  overflow: hidden;
}
@-webkit-keyframes winkle {
  0%, 100% {
    height: 0;
    color: red;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    height: auto;
    color: blue;
  }
}
@keyframes winkle {
  0%, 100% {
    height: 0;
    color: red;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    height: auto;
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right, you can't animate something that not exists anymore. So you have to use another way to hide this element, like height or opacity, look this eg to see the differences:

## Winkle with Height

This example winkle the **li** but the list will move because the height changes.

```css
li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear;
  animation: winkle 1s linear;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 1s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 1s;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 2s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 2s;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 3s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 3s;
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 4s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 4s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes winkle {
  0%, 100% {
    height:0;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    height:20px;
  }
}
@keyframes winkle {
  0%, 100% {
    height:0;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    height:20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

## Winkle with Opacity

This example winkle the **li** but the list mantain the original height.

```css
li:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear;
  animation: winkle 1s linear;
}
li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 1s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 1s;
}
li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 2s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 2s;
}
li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 3s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 3s;
}
li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-animation: winkle 1s linear 4s;
  animation: winkle 1s linear 4s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes winkle {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
@keyframes winkle {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    opacity:1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't.

Properties which are not animatable are not animatable period.

There is no state between `display: none` and `display: block` (as there is between `height: 0` and `height: 500px`) so you can't animate between them.

Comment: What about heights? heights are animatable!

Comment: You can animate the height (to fixed values, not auto), but not the display.

Comment: You cannot animate to 'auto'

Answer (score 0):

CSS animations and transitions work by creating steps between two numeric values, for example:

```
height: 0px -> height: 100px;
```

In this case, given the amount of steps and timing, the browser can calculate a transition between both values. It comes down to math.

On the other hand, non numeric CSS properties only have 2 possible states (on / off), and therefore can't have any "inbetween" steps:

```
display: none -> display: block;
```

All CSS propeties can be used in an animation or transition, just take into account if that value can take progressive steps between two values.